# ASP.NET Webform not creating LocalDb database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, webforms

I am starting a ASP.NET Webforms application in Visual Studio 2015 and I am trying to add my models to a database using Entity Framework Code First but the database file is not showing up. I am using the SQL Server Express LocalDB that comes when installing VS for simplicity. I have the following code set up to create and populate my model.

The model class "Monster":

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace MonsterMadness.Models
{
    public class Monster
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int MonsterId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int AttackPower { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Defence { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int ChanceToHit { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Dodge { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Critical { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My DB context class "MonsterMadnessContext":

```cs
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace MonsterMadness.Models
{
    public class MonsterMadnessContext : DbContext
    {
        public MonsterMadnessContext() : base("MonsterMadness")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Monster> Monsters
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
}
```

My initializer "MonsterMadnessDatabaseInitializer":

```cs
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace MonsterMadness.Models
{
    public class MonsterMadnessDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MonsterMadnessContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(MonsterMadnessContext context)
        {
            GetMonsters().ForEach(monster => context.Monsters.Add(monster));
        }

        private static List<Monster> GetMonsters()
        {
            List<Monster> monsters = new List<Monster>
            {
                new Monster()
                {
                    Name = "Test 1",
                    AttackPower = 10,
                    ChanceToHit = 10,
                    Critical = 10,
                    Defence = 10,
                    Dodge = 10
                },
                new Monster()
                {
                    Name = "Test 2",
                    AttackPower = 20,
                    ChanceToHit = 20,
                    Critical = 20,
                    Defence = 20,
                    Dodge = 20
                }
            };

            return monsters;
        }
    }
}
```

I have my initializer being run in the Global.ascx file:

```cs
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        //Initialize database
        Database.SetInitializer(new MonsterMadnessDatabaseInitializer());
    }
}
```

And lastly my web.config entry for the "MonsterMadess" connection string which should be pointing to LocalDB:

```cs
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MonsterMadness" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v12.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\monstermadness.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I set up everything based on [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create_the_data_access_layer) but whenever I run the application I do not see the mdf file being created. Since I have an initializer being run there should be data in the table and the file should be created. What am I missing? Thanks for the help.

Comment: DO you get an runtime error while executing the application ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound I'm not seeing any exceptions and I have it set to break on all CLR exceptions when thrown. I'm not accessing the table yet since I wanted to see it be created first, if that changes anything.

Comment: Your tutorial say that the database will be created when the application first run. By lauching tha application this will not create the database. You must query your database by using your some code like `MonsterMadnessContext.Monsters.ToList()`

Comment: @CodeNotFound So apparently I need to learn to read better, thanks a lot for pointing that out. Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: No problem. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into **context constructor**:

```
Database.SetInitializer(
    new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MonsterMadnessContext>());
```